# Input integers into array and then search that array for the integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

I'm trying to create an HTML page that allows the user to input integers into a stored array using a button and then search that array for the inputted integers using another button. I am very confused and new to coding so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. To have a better chance of getting an answer to your question, I would suggest you taking a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In the meantime, some things you should address in your question are: what have you tried (include code), what is your intended output, what output are you getting, and what have you researched to try and figure out the issue. Good luck with your new coding journey.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="data">[]</p>
    <input id="inputNumber" value="0"/> <button id="pushBtn" onclick="push()">PUSH</button>
    <input id="findNumber" value="0"/> <button id="pushBtn" onclick="find()">FIND</button>
    <script>
      var data = [];
      function push(e) {
        var toAdd = document.getElementById("inputNumber").value;
        data.push(toAdd);
        refresh();
      }
      function find(e) {
        var toFind = document.getElementById("findNumber").value;
        for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
          if(data[i]==toFind) return alert("found at "+i);
        }
        return alert("couldn't find that number");
      }
      function refresh(){
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = data;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically, I'm just using using the buttons to call the functions within the script that handles insertion and query for me. Additionally a refresh function is there to refresh the newly added data